# Avoid global functions when compiling typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, obfuscation

How can I avoid the creation of global functions when compiling typescript into javascript.

Benefit: obfuscator won't have to provide a public API

Foo.ts:

```
class Foo {}
```

Foo.js:

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    return Foo;
}());
```

Foo.obfuscated.js (using npm jsobfuscator):

```
var _0xcd14=[];var _0x12e2=[];var Foo=(function(){function Foo(){}return Foo}())
```

**Foo is still visible**. I understand why (public API). Solution would be:

Foo.isolated.js:

```
(function() { /* code from Foo.js */ })();
```

Foo.isolated.obfuscated.js (**what I want**):

```
var _0xe1f1=[];var _0xa6a8=[];(function(){var _0x64f8x2=(function(){function _0x64f8x2(){}return _0x64f8x2}())})()
```

Is there a typescript setup for `tsconfig.js` / compiler options like `isolation: true` or something?

Comment: consider using modules, and if that's too much for you - just use a self-calling function.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the class inside a function scope should do the trick.

```
(function(){
    class Foo {}
})
```

There isn't built in support in the form of an option as far as I am aware. Let me know if doing the above does not achieve your aim - in which case some more details about exactly what the goal is will help us understand what you're going for here.

Answer (score 0):

nested (private) class ?

```
module MyModule {
    export class MyPublicClass {
        private myPrivateClass: PrivateClass;
        constructor() {
            this.myPrivateClass = new PrivateClass;
        }
        public test() {
            this.myPrivateClass.test();
        }
    }

    class PrivateClass {
        public test() {
            console.log('it works');
        }
    }
}
```